# Wordpress translate search query and link to external url

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to modify WordPress search form, so that after user enters the word in the search bar, that word would be translated and accordingly redirected into external link (for example google). I managed to do translation, redirection, but struggle to get search query in first place.

My code:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform"   role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="" target="_blank"  >
    
    <input  type="text" id="SearchText"  value="" name="SearchText"   placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr($search_text) ;?>" >
 
    <button onclick="go()" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btnsearch"></button>
  
</form>
```

Then code for translation needs input for search query $XXXXXXXXXXXXX:

```
 $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($XXXXXXXXXXXXX) . '&source=xx&target=en';
 $str = $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

Then I have script that would take translated search query $str:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function go() {
   document.myform.action = "https://www.google.com/";
   document.myform.SearchText.value = "<?php echo $str ?>";

...............
}
</script>
```

Everything works if I put any word instead $XXXXXXXXXXXXX, but the question what here needs to be entered so that it would take original search entry.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to receive a request passed in a get parameter? You can use jquery `$.get` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/